# How to create custom button onClick() event Android(Studio)?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating my first Android App, and as part of it, I need to add new buttons after a click on another button.

Then I need to `create()` a button after a `onClick()` event on another button.

How to do it?
Things you should know:

- I am using Android Studio to develop the app,
- I have already imported these:

  ```
  import android.view.*;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  ```
- And I'd like to know where to get the whole Library list for android, or better, I'd like you to say what's your best android library to develop on such these things, I need to find and get experienced on a library so I'll need suggestions!

Thanks a lot in advance :)

P.S. Just typed those `create()` and `onClick()` to make it clear that I was talking about methods, but not that both of 'em are real ones or the ones I'll need ;)

P.P.S. I don't know how many buttons will be ther becuase I do NOT choose that, the user does, it's somethig like: I want to create a new thing, then I press the button '+' and create a new button (the new thing), for this reason, the amount of buttons isn't known, that's why I can't use the visibility trick, but yeah I first thought about that aswell!

Answer (score 1):

rockfight's answer is correct, but I would recommend you to use the button in your layout with android:visibility="gone" and then show it when the user taps on the  first button using button2.setVisibility(View.Visible).
It's always easier to create your layouts and views in xml instead of code.
Personally, I'm using support-v4 library, recyclerview, recently-released design library and some of the Google Play Services libraries.

EDIT: if you're going to add a lot of buttons, and you don't know how many, I'd recommend you to use ListView or RecyclerView. I personally prefer RecyclerView, but it might be more difficult to set up. Anyway, you'll be adding items to your list. That items are basically buttons, so your item layout would look like this:

```
item_layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is a new button!"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:translationZ="6dp" />
    <!-- Material Design. See http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android- -->
    <!-- The attributes you need...... -->
```

That's all. You don't have to mess with ugly code. If you want to get an idea of the advantages of RecyclerView, see http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button object

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
```

Then add button to your layout

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
layout.addView(myButton);
```

I am not sure what library are you talking about. To learn about android go to [android developer website](http://developer.android.com/index.html) and click search button and search what you want to know. You will get all libraries there.

Comment: Yes thanks I guess this is the code that gets closest to what I meant, now I'm updating my question with more info

Answer (score 0):

You do not need libraries for making onClick methods. When you have your button, set onClick method like this: `button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener...)` if you press Ctrl+Space you will get possible choices of what to choose.
How many buttons do you wish to add programmatically? Maybe it would be better if you create buttons in xml and use `Visibility.GONE` and `Visibility.VISIBLE` if there are not many buttons and you know the end number of them.

Comment: Well technically, you could add one button after the other in a pre-constructed Linear Layout but that is very inefficient. You construct button as @rockfight said above Button b = new Button(this) and you assignt layout params to it. Maybe consider doing this with a ListView where user would add new line to the list

Comment: Yes..! I think that might work, so that every item will be displayed right?

Comment: What ya think @slorangex ?

Comment: Yes, the best way is to go with `RecyclerView` I think. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), it's a new kind of ListView and it's very efficient.